# Remove a ver parameter from a URL - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm currently working on a Wordpress website and I'm running into an issue.

The code in my functions file to enqueue the .js file is:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'esro', 'https://tickets.leicesterymca.co.uk/Iframe/esrojsapi.js', '', false );
```

However, when I look at the source code for my site, it's showing the following URL for the .js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://tickets.leicesterymca.co.uk/Iframe/esrojsapi.js?ver=4.7.3"></script>
```

I have been told that the problems I'm having might be down to the perimeter at the end of this URL: ?ver=4.7.3 and to remove it.

I guess I would rather stop it from being there in the first place than add more code to remove it but I'm not even sure thats an option?

So firstly, how is it getting there and where is it coming from? Secondly, how can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the 4th parameter to null rather than false like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'esro', 'https://tickets.leicesterymca.co.uk/Iframe/esrojsapi.js', '', null );
```

From the docs:

```
$ver
(string|bool|null) (Optional) String specifying script version number, if it 
has one, which is added to the URL as a query string for cache busting 
purposes. If version is set to false, a version number is automatically added 
equal to current installed WordPress version. If set to null, no version is added.
```

Comment: Ah ok - Excellent! Thanks